# AWS CloudFormation Template Format Error: Unresolved Resource Dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm encountering an issue with an AWS CloudFormation template where I'm trying to create nested stacks for managing CloudTrail permissions and filters. However, I'm running into a "Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies" when attempting to create the nested stack for CloudTrail permissions.

Here's a simplified version of my CloudFormation templates:

Parent Stack (parent_stack.yml):

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  pAccountIds1:
    Description: First 100 list of member account ids to grant CloudTrail log access.
    Type: String
    Default: ''
Outputs:
  Main:
    Description: Cloudtrail filter for the first 100 member accounts.
    Value: !Ref pAccountIds1
Resources:
  nestedCloudTrailFilter:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        pAccountIds1: !Ref pAccountIds1
      TemplateURL: nested_cloudtrail_filter_template.yml
  nestedCloudTrailPermission:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    DependsOn:
      - nestedCloudTrailFilter
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        pAccountIds1: !Ref pAccountIds1
        pDatabaseName: 'amazon_security_lake_glue_db_eu_west_1'
        pCloudtrailTableName: 'amazon_security_lake_table_eu_west_1_cloud_trail_mgmt_1_0'
      TemplateURL: nested_cloudtrail_permission_template.yml
```

Child Stack (nested_cloudtrail_filter_template.yml):

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
###
## Parameters
Parameters:
  pAccountIds1:
    Description: First 100 list of member account ids to grant Cloudtrail log access.
    Type: String
    Default: ''
  pDatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_glue_db_eu_west_1'
  pCloudtrailTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_table_eu_west_1_cloud_trail_mgmt_1_0'


## Resources
Resources:
  'Fn::ForEach::CloudtrailShares':
    - AccountId
    - !Split [",",
        !Join [",", [!Ref pAccountIds1]]
      ]
    - 'CloudtrailFilter${AccountId}':
        Type: AWS::LakeFormation::DataCellsFilter
        Properties:
          TableCatalogId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          DatabaseName: !Ref pDatabaseName
          TableName: !Ref pCloudtrailTableName
          Name: !Join ['_',['cloudtrail',!Ref AccountId]]
          RowFilter:
            FilterExpression: !Sub "accountid='${AccountId}'"
          ColumnWildcard: {}
```

Child Stack (nested_cloudtrail_permission_template.yml):

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
###
## Parameters
Parameters:
  pAccountIds1:
    Description: First 100 list of member account ids to grant Cloudtrail log access.
    Type: String
    Default: ''
  pDatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_glue_db_eu_west_1'
  pCloudtrailTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_table_eu_west_1_cloud_trail_mgmt_1_0'

Outputs:
  CloudtrailPermission:
    Description: Cloudtrail filter for the first 100 member accounts.
    Value: !Ref pAccountIds1

Resources:
  'Fn::ForEach::CloudtrailShares':
    - AccountId
    - !Split [",",
        !Join [",", [!Ref pAccountIds1]]
      ]
    - 'CloudtrailPermission${AccountId}':
        Type: AWS::LakeFormation::PrincipalPermissions
        Properties:
          Principal:
            DataLakePrincipalIdentifier: !Ref AccountId
          Permissions: ['SELECT']
          PermissionsWithGrantOption: ['SELECT']
          Resource:
            DataCellsFilter:
              TableCatalogId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
              Name: !Select
                      - 3
                      - !Split
                        - '|'
                        - !Ref
                            Fn::Sub: 'CloudtrailFilter${AccountId}' 
              TableName: !Ref pCloudtrailTableName
              DatabaseName: !Ref pDatabaseName
```

When I attempt to create the parent stack, I encounter the error: "Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [CloudtrailFilter981813074321] in the Resources block of the template."

I believe the issue lies in how I'm referencing resources between the parent and child stacks, particularly with the `CloudtrailFilter` resource in the `nested_cloudtrail_permission_template.yml` stack. How can I resolve this dependency issue and successfully create my CloudFormation stack?

Comment: what do you mean and which file I making mistake

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Ref in the Name, can you construct the name manually? That resource is not in the child template, so it can't resolve it. Otherwise you will need to use an Output from the other template and pass in the value as a parameter.

```yaml
Name: !Select
         - 3
         - !Split
           - '|'
           - !Ref Fn::Sub: 'CloudtrailFilter${AccountId}'
```